# Efficient way to merge dictionaries while removing duplicates using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given an array of dictionaries in javascript, I want to merge them so that they don't contain any duplicates. For example given

```
jsons1 = [{"a": "xyz"}, {"a": 12}]
jsons2 = [{"a": "xyz"}, {"a", 13}]
```

I want to return a new array that removes the duplicates while merging

```
jsons3 = [{"a": "xyz"}, {"a": 12}, {"a": 13}]
```

order isnt important

This is what I did:

```
let jsons1 = [
    {
        "a": "xyz"
    
    }, 
    {
        "a": 4
    
    }, 
    {
        "a": 1
    
    }, 
  
]


let jsons2 = [
    {
        "a": "xyz"
    
    }, 
    {
        "a": 4
    
    }, 
    {
        "a": 6
    
    }, 
  
]

const val = [jsons1, jsons2]

let filtered = []
for(json of val) {
    for(obj of json) {
    let match = false;
    for(dict of filtered) {
        if(JSON.stringify(dict) === JSON.stringify(obj)) {
        match = true;
        break
      }
    }
    if(match == true) {
        continue
    }
    filtered.push(obj)

    }
}

console.log(filtered)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awb6qnzo/6/

Basically I create a new array called `filtered` and I then iterate through each jsons array. I then iterate through filtered to check if that obj is already in it.

although it works, its extremely inefficient. Is there a simpler way?

Edit: Changing question to specific values since the former is apparently not possible

Given an array of dictionaries in javascript, I want to merge them so that they don't contain any duplicates (on the key "id"). E.g.

```
jsons1 = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 12}]
jsons2 = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}]
```

I want to return a new array that removes the duplicates while merging

```
jsons3 = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 12}]
```

Comment: Do you need deep comparison or are these dictionaries just keys to primitive values.

Comment: deep comparison

Comment: this doesn't work if a given object can have multiple keys, ie `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `{"b":2, "a":1}` will fail a stringify comparison since the key order isn't guaranteed in js

Comment: ok i change my question to specific values

Comment: @bryan60, order of properties is reliable nowadays, https://dev.to/frehner/the-order-of-js-object-keys-458d. That doesn't mean it's a good way of checking object equality but it is no longer true that object properties are not guaranteed when iterating.

Comment: @JuanMendes run `JSON.stringify({"B":1, "A":2})` and `JSON.stringify({"A":2, "B":1})` ... saying that it's reliable is misleading as it's reliable to be in order of chronological property creation. which still breaks stringify as an object comparison

Comment: @bryan60 You are right, the string keys are ordered by insertion order, unless they can be coerced into a number. Which is why I said it's still not a good way to check equality. I'm just saying the iteration order of both objects is guaranteed 

Comment: @JuanMendes allow me to amend my comment: `since the key order isn't guaranteed in js in a way that makes it useful for object comparisons`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's reword the problem and pretend we have a function `equals` that checks if two objects are the same, first.

We want to *concat*enate all the values in jsons2 that satisfy some condition.

To do that, we need to *filter* out objects that don't satisfy the condition.

This condition is that every object in jsons1 does not equal the object in jsons2.

Another way to put this is the negation of *some* object in jsons1 is equal to the object in jsons2.

```js
jsons1.concat(
    jsons2.filter(
        (a) => !jsons1.some((b) => equals(a, b))
    )
);
```

You can write `equals` anyway you want, as long as it functions correctly.